# How to count duplicate items in an array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a string array of names or could be a List of names which can have multiple duplicate names.  What I want to do is to get a list of top 5 most duplicate names. Could someone tell me what's the best way to do this?

```
 Array[0] = 'Mike'
 Array[1] = 'Tim'
 Array[2] = 'Debra'
 Array[3] = 'Mike'
 Array[4] = 'Steve'
 Array[5] = 'Mike'
 Array[6] = 'Amy'
 Array[7] = 'Tim'
 Array[8] = 'Debra'
 Array[9] = 'Amy'
```

Output:  Mike has 3
         Tim has 2
         Debra has 2
         Steve has 1
         Amy has 1

Comment: A good way to start is to pick a better title for your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it can be done with grouping:

```
var result = from name in namesArray
             group name by name into g
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

If you need just top 5 - call `.Take(5)` of that:

```
var result = (from name in namesArray
             group name by name into g
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).Take(5);
```

Comment: How about if it is a List? How do I apply the above grouping to a List? Thanks.

Comment: @user1387287, Nothing changes. Literally, absolutely nothing. They both implement `IEnumerable<>`, that's all that required

Comment: So how do I add the .Take(5) to the above statement?

Comment: Thank you all, you guys are awsomeeeeeeeeee... :)

Comment: I got the code above to run without error but the result count is 0. This is my code:      var topFive = (from name in pgmTallyList
                          group name by name into g
                          orderby g.Count() descending
                          select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).Take(5);

Comment: @user1387287, can you show the actual code? How did you get the 0 result? [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/UshEEK) is this code working (on a simpler input, but still)

Comment: Ok, I got it to work now.  You code is perfect, it's my typing :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `GroupBy`.

```
var result = Array
  .GroupBy(x => x) 
  .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key; Count = x.Count() })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
  .Take(5);
```

Comment: @user1387287 yes, this will work with any type that implements `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you want to do something with Linq,

```
var results = from name in names
              group name by name into nameGroup
              let count = nameGroup.Count()
              orderby count descending
              take 5
              select new {Value = name, Count = count};
```

After which you can format the contents of the `results` as you desire.